# Finite Group with Equally Sized Conjugacy Classes is Abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

I was working on an exercise where I had to proof this and its converse. The converse I already worked out, but I am struggling with this part.

So far I've deducted that if all conjugacy classes are the same size, they must be of size 1, since $C(e)=\{e\}$. So, now I've somehow got to show that $\forall x,y\in G:xy=yx$, where $G$ is a group.

Since they are all in a different conjagacy class we know there $\exists g\in G:gx=xg$. If this was 'for all' instead we would be done.

Comment: @AnuragA I don't see how you go from $ghg^{-1}=g$ to $gh=hg$, or even for that fact why the initial statement needs to hold.

Comment: @JelleDijkstra Most probably that was a typo: what was meant is that $\;ghg^{-1}=h\;$ **for all** $\;g,h\in G\;$ ...

Comment: @AnuragA Your first equality has a rather important typo and you can't edit it anymore, so perhaps you should delete it. It should be $\;ghg^{-1}=\color{red}h\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I understand we want to show the equality you mentioned, but now how it is derived.

Answer (score 1):

If all the conjugacy classes have size $\;1\;$ , then for **any** $\;g\in G\;$ we have

$$\{g\}=\mathcal Orb(g)=\{hgh^{-1}\;/\;h\in G\}\implies g=hgh^{-1}\;\;\forall\,h\in G\implies gh=hg\;\;\forall\,g,h\in G\implies$$

$\;G\;$ is abelian and we're done.

Comment: If we look at $\mathbb{z}_4$ we have equally sized conjugacy classes, but we have $Orb(1)=\{ 0,1,2,3\}\neq \{ 1\}$.

Comment: @JelleDijkstra What $\;g\;$ in $\;\Bbb Z_4\;$ are you talking about...? For any element in $\;\Bbb Z_4\;$ , its conjugacy class is **exactly** the element itself! That is an abelian group: it cannot be otherwise!

Comment: I was looking at $g=1$.

Comment: @JelleDijkstra Well, then $\;\mathcal Orb(1)=\{1\}\;$ , of course....how would you get $\;0, 2\;$ or $\;3\;$ ? Impossible, of course...

Comment: Following the definition of an orbit I found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Orbit_(Group_Theory)) we could use $x=1$ and $g=1$ to get $2$.

Comment: @JelleDijkstra No, of course not...! Perhaps you're fogetting the group action here is **addition modulo** $\;4\;$ ? And then we get: $$xgx^{-1}=1+1+(-1)=1+0=1=g\;\ldots$$ You could put $\;-1=3\pmod4\;$ as well, if you prefer that notation. It just is the same, of course.

Comment: I really don't understand the concept of an orbit then. I think this exercise is not possible with my current understanding of group theory so far.

Comment: @JelleDijkstra I agree. I think you may also be lacking some work with more basic notions in group theory, and how "the product" in a group can be several different things: in the group of square matrices of order $\;n\;$ over some field, "the product" means matrix multiplication, in the group of all bijections of a set, "the product" is composition of functions, in the abelian cyclic group $\;\Bbb Z_n=\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\;$ , "the product" is addition modulo $\;n\;$ , etc.

Comment: This is not discussed in my booklet until 3 chapters later.

Comment: @JelleDijkstra I see...then I've no idea whatsoever how is it expected from you to understand all the things involved in such a question. Honest....but perhaps someone else has.